# Как записать из базы строку вида 4,3.5 в отдельные строки другой бд?

Tags: php, mysql

Помогите решить...

У меня есть таблица радиостанций в ней есть поле genres в нем записаны id стилей музыки таблицы genres.

Но мне надо сделать иначе.

переписать все стили относящиеся к радиостанции в отдельную базу genres_radio.

Т.е. радиостанция с id 123 имеет стили с id 4,5,6,7 и в базе genres_radio должно быть записано id_radio 123 и id_genres 4 и т.д.

Как мне написать скрипт который вытащит из таблицы радиостанций из поля 4,5,6,7 и добавит в базу genres_radio

Не могу понять как подскажите...

Comment: Т.е. они у вас сейчас в текстовом поле лежат через запятую, а вам надо привести к нормальной структуре по одной записи на жанр каждой станции ? И под "другой базой данных" имеется ввиду другая таблица в той же базе или в другой базе на другом сервере ?

Comment: совершенно верно https://i.gyazo.com/cca491fd7b97fa25cc2f912c9898dee6.png - база радиостанций https://i.gyazo.com/feb197a891781bad0ed8a5e56353a99f.png  - база id стилей и id радио

Comment: Ответ написан. Добавлю, что в таблице genres_radio поле ID не нужно. в ней достаточно двух полей с данными id_radio и id_genres, причем primary key в таблице обявляется сразу по обоим полям `primary key(id_radio,id_genres)`. Это обеспечит невозможность дать одной радиостанции один и тот же стиль два раза, что ваша текущая таблица в принципе позволяет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать одним запросом:

```
insert into genres_radio(id_radio,id_genres)
 select R.id, G.id
   from `radio` R
   join `genres` G on FIND_IN_SET(G.id,R.genres)>0
```

Где `radio` - таблица радиостанций, `genres` - таблица со списком стилей.

Comment: одним запросом что ли все делается?

Comment: @AlexanderSizintsev Да, именно так. Сначала проверьте сам select, что он выдал правдоподобные данные, потом к нему в начале припишите `insert into ...` и все, он вставит в таблицу то, что сформировал select

Comment: чет не работает mysql_query("insert into genres_radio(id_radio,id_genres)
 select R.id, G.id
   from `station` R
   join `genres` G on FIND_IN_SET(G.id,R.genres)>0");

Comment: @AlexanderSizintsev вы посмотрите какие он ошибки пишет, может у вас колонки как нибудь по другому называются, у вас айди-поля в таблицах жанров и станций просто ID зовутся ? И выполните его лучше в каком нибудь mysql workbench или самой утилите mysql. разовая же работа

Comment: @AlexanderSizintsev Вот, вижу на вашей картинке с примером таблицы поле с жанрами названо `genre`, а в вопросе вы написали с буквой s `genres` и в запросе я так же написал ...

Comment: точно! отлично сработало!